# Removing element from array doesn't change graphic

Tags: java, arrays, netbeans

In my application, I made an array to control the flag images in my output. This worked fine but when I remove an element from my array the picture doesn't change at all.

```
class Flag{

Image FlagImage;
int FlagNum = 0;

public Flag(int FlagNum)  {
    this.FlagNum = FlagNum;
    try{
    FlagImage = ImageIO.read(new File("flag1.png"));
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
}

public void Update() {

}

public void Draw(Graphics g) {
    //Draw Flag
    g.drawImage(FlagImage, ((FlagNum) % 3+1) * 100-100, (int)((FlagNum) / 3) * 100+100, null);
}

}
public class Flags extends JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form Flags
 */
public Flags(){
    initComponents();
    FlagSet.add(new Flag(1));
    final Timer timer =new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e){
            repaint();
            for (Flag f: FlagSet){
                f.Update();
            }
        }
    });

}

public static ArrayList<Flag> FlagSet = new ArrayList();

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

    super.paintComponent(g);

    for (Flag f: FlagSet){
        f.Draw(g);

    }
}
```

I then try to add flags like so:

```
flagCounter = 4;
while(flagCounter > -1){
    Flags.FlagSet.add(new Flag(flagCounter));
    flagCounter--;
}
```

Which works fine but my image doesn't change if I put in a `Flgas.FlageSet.remove(//Some flag)`later on. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a `repaint()`?

Comment: I am new to java. How do I use repaint? I think you answered my question.

Comment: Also how would I add a shortdelay before paint

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove a particular element from an array in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-to-remove-a-particular-element-from-an-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a call to `repaint()`.

Repaint is a signal sent to the drawing component to tell it that something has changed, and that it needs to call the `paint` methods again.  In this case, as your addition to your `Flags` list will change how it is drawn, you should simply call `repaint()` after you've finished adding your flags.

Comment: Thank you. How would you add a delay in front of it?

Comment: @mtheorylord: Google [Java Swing delay](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=java+swing+delay), and you'll find out about [Swing Timers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) in the first 3 hits.

Comment: Thank you very much. Both of you.